# how to replace values in a dictionary inside of a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

so for example, here is the a list

```
my_list = [{'name':'Tomy', 'review':98, 'job':'engineer'},
           {'name':'John', 'review':52, 'job':'engineer'},
           {'name':'Mike', 'review':77, 'job':'developer'},
           {'name':'Jay', 'review':68, 'job':'student'}]
```

so based on the review score of these people,
I want to group it by 'low score' and 'high score'
if review score is lower than 75, then 'low score', else 'high score'

so here is what I expected,

```
my_list = [{'name':'Tomy', 'review':'high score', 'job':'engineer'},
           {'name':'John', 'review':'low score', 'job':'engineer'},
           {'name':'Mike', 'review':'high score', 'job':'developer'},
           {'name':'Jay', 'review':'low score', 'job':'student'}]
```

so I tried to do this:

```
for i in my_list:
   for score in i['review']:
         if score<=75:
            i['review']='low score'
         else:
            i['review']='high score'
```

however, this seems keep running with an error that the my_list is not a dictionary...
can anyone help with it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `for score in i['review']:`, you attempt to iterate through a scalar. This is not possible, and this line is not needed. The outer loop suffices:

```
for i in my_list:
    i['review'] = 'low score' if i['review'] <= 75 else 'high score'
```